# Running a Spring + React Application - Node Issue

Tags: java, node.js, spring, reactjs, maven

I'm attempting to run the bundled Spring + React Application provided by Spring [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-1-basic-features) - I'm behind a corporate firewall so naturally I'm running into some dependency issues.

Every `<dependency>` in the `pom` installs fine, but the following execution(s) fails

```
<execution>
    <id>install node and npm</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v4.4.5</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>3.9.2</npmVersion>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>npm install</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>install</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I  get the following error after running an `mvn install`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-
plugin:1.2:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project hello-spring-react: 
Could not download Node.js from: https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/win-x64/node.exe: 
Could not download https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/win-x64/node.exe: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I have a local installation of node and npm, so I'm wondering if it will be possible to utilize them (rather than resolve the apparent Certificate issue)?  If not, could someone explain to my why and/or how to resolve this Certificate error?

Thanks much!

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html

Comment: Thanks @OrthoHomeDefense I'll check it out